# JSqlParser：CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql) Exception;

Tags: sql, sql-server, jsqlparser

In the sqlserver 2008:

```
/**
 sql1：use Subquery AS 'PIVOT' ResultSet
*/
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.Station_ID stationId, b.Factor_Code factoryCode, a.Value value 
    FROM T_Data_Real a 
    LEFT JOIN T_Bas_Factor b ON a.Factor_ID = b.Id
)f
PIVOT (max(f.value) for f.factoryCode in (ZD, COD, SW, PH))d

/**
 sql2：use with
*/
WITH A AS(
    SELECT a.Station_ID stationId, b.Factor_Code factoryCode, a.Value value 
    FROM T_Data_Real a 
    LEFT JOIN T_Bas_Factor b ON a.Factor_ID = b.Id)
SELECT * FROM A
PIVOT (max(value) for factoryCode in (ZD, COD, SW, PH))d
```

Executing the above two statements in SSMS has the same result.

but When I use the method  to format sql 1 and 2：

```
CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql)
```

**The first one throws an exception，I can't use Subquery AS 'PIVOT' ResultSet.**

The Exception Message like this:

```
net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:56)
    at spring.commons.api.test.sqltest.test1(sqltest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:83)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:61)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "PIVOT" "pivot "" at line 1, column 184.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "JOIN" ...
    "LEFT" ...
    "CROSS" ...
    "FULL" ...
    "WHERE" ...
    "FOR" ...
    "UNION" ...
    "GROUP" ...
    "INNER" ...
    "ORDER" ...
    "RIGHT" ...
    "HAVING" ...
    "NATURAL" ...
    "INTERSECT" ...
    "EXCEPT" ...
    "MINUS" ...
    "START" ...
    "CONNECT" ...
    ";" ...
    "," ...
    "ORDER" ...
    "ORDER" ...

    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.generateParseException(CCJSqlParser.java:16869)
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.jj_consume_token(CCJSqlParser.java:16722)
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Statement(CCJSqlParser.java:91)
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:54)
    ... 40 more
```

please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with JSqlParser. I filed an issue (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/473) for that.

The problem is the alias for the subquery in combination with the pivot table.

Therefore this one should work with your version:

```
select * from (select * from mytable) pivot ( ... )
```

---

Fixed it. Try using **JSqlParser 1.2-SNAPSHOT**. This version is not yet deployed, you have to compile it yourself.